# Trying to print email with PDF attachment without opening attachment

Tags: windows-7, windows, pdf, printing, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am having trouble printing emails **with** `PDF` attachments without opening the attachment first.

I want to be able to simply select the email, go to `File > Print` and print the email itself alongside the attachment.

[image]

This is something I *should* be able to do considering the above Print options I set.

**However;**

I am encountering a problem where it attempts to open the PDF file and then prints the email **Without** the attachment.  This happens on my default printer, as it states in the printer options is required.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to get this working properly.

Seems a little strange that the options is provided yet it cannot seem to print the most common type of attachment.

**My attempts**

I notice some suggestions claiming that Outlook needs to be *Run as Administrator*.  This is something that I already have attempted, to no avail.

Looks like a number of people are having similar issues on Adobe's support forums, but have yet to get an answer.

**Software**

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Outlook 2016
- Adobe Reader DC V2017.009.20044

**Printer**

- CopyStar CS5550ci

Comment: Outlook is supposed to: Open the file with default program -> Print in default program -> Close file. And repeat for each attachment, can you do this process manually and it work properly? Is Adobe Reader the default program for pdf files?

Comment: @fernando.reyes I am able to do this manually, yes.  Adobe reader is also the current default.  It seems to open the `.pdf` file in Adobe, but does not progress any further than that when I attempt to print the entire email (Attachment included)

Comment: Looks like the problem has been identified in Adobe Reader DC and not answered: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2088409 You can try some of the solutions on that forum or install some other pdf reader

Comment: @fernando.reyes After attempting a number of the makeshift Solutions other users attempted, I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions related to this problem, first when you have several printers and you try to print to the default printer.

1. If you are trying to print the mails to your default printer, if you check the Microsoft information page about [this feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Print-attachments-received-in-email-messages-30fb682d-d311-4a17-ba5e-8409ca6f776e) there is a note saying:

> NOTE:  Attachments print only to the default printer. For example, if
>   printer A is the default, and you choose to print a message that has
>   an attachment on printer B, the message prints on printer B, but the
>   attachment prints on printer A. If you want to send the attachment to
>   a specific printer, double-click the attachment to open it, and then
>   in the program that opens the attachment, use the print command.

So, if you are trying to print somewhere different to your default printer, it will not print.

2. There a problem detected with Adobe Reader DC, that has been around for more than a year and looks like it has still no solution.

It doesn't happen to everyone, and by what I understand of the proposed solution it happens when your printer has a short name, then Adobe Reader DC can't send the document to print.

For this reason there are several solution proposed, being the easier one to install some other PDF reader, if having Adobe's is not a requirement.

You can check [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2088409) in Adobe's forum for more info.

Comment: This happens on my default printer as well.  Let me throw my attempts in as an edit, sorry for not providing in the original question.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I updated the answer with Adobe's forum proposed solution. Hope this helps

Comment: While Adobe is a requirement, I have also tried this with one other reader and had the same problem.  **Foxit Reader** to be exact.